# IB: Use Auto Layout?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I am slowly becoming more comfortable with programming in a Mac environment after moving across from Windows where I was using C#.

The transition has been smooth so fare but with a very steep learning curve getting used to Objective-C. I am finding Objective-C an amazing spin on a C stye language and so happy I made the move.

I am using XCode 4.6 on OSX 10.8.2 and iOS 6.1.2

The application I’m working on is an OSX Checklist that will need to communicate with a iOS equivalent.

The OSX side of it comes first and it includes a NSOutlineView to use like a SideBar.

I have been having a little trouble positioning controls and having them size to what I want them to do.

I have just found in XCode’s IB a switch that may solve the issue.

In the File Inspector there is a switch for: Use Auto Layout, which is currently ticked. When I Build the project I have a application that runs.

[image]

As soon as I remove the tick and re-Build the application it crashes with the following errors, plus more:

```
2013-02-24 17:00:17.988 ServiceCheck[1633:303] *** Assertion failure in -[NSTableRowData insertRowsAtIndexes:withRowAnimation:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.34/TableView.subproj/NSTableRowData.m:5408
2013-02-24 17:00:17.989 ServiceCheck[1633:303] An uncaught exception was raised
2013-02-24 17:00:17.989 ServiceCheck[1633:303] insertRowsAtIndexes:withRowAnimation: can not happen while updating visible rows!
```

I am having trouble on what’s needed to resolve the error and allow me to manually size the controls to my likings.

To help, I can attached my code (once I work out how) for you to better understand what I am seeing.

Comment: I've no idea why Autolayout would have anything to do with that crash, but I've written about using interface builder and Autolayout, which you may find useful: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/18/autolayout-in-interface-builder/

Comment: Thanks for that....   I'll have a read...   it may also help achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  Took a look at your paper and I think I can do what is needed going in this direction.  I will find out tonight.

Comment: Josh knows his stuff but I'm pretty sure he's not writing articles on my blog!

Comment: Brain-Fade....    :-)